# How can I redirect a page url (example.com/pageurl) from my domain registrar?

Tags: redirect, dns

So I have a Tumblr, which means I can't use htaccess, and am hoping there's a way I can redirect page url (example.com/post/2234324/posttitle to example.com/page), purely from my registrar (Namecheap).

Is there host records I can change, or something else, to redirect urls on my domain?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your DNS and can add A records, etc. then look at CNAME record.  Here you can enter an alias domain.  This is commonly used with Amazon S3 when you set cdn.myco.com and your amazon bucket is cdn.myco.com.amazons3.com or if you use Google Apps for Business to manage your email.

- SEE: http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58317
- good instructions for various hosts

Comment: Hmm, right, but is there a way to simply redirect URLs inside my tumblr (mytumblog.com/post/2234324/posttitle to mytumblog.com/page)?

Comment: it's tough if you don't have .htaccess or rewrite capabilities. not sure on Namecheap's capabilities but if you did look at DNS, CNAME would be what you'd want to do.

Comment: what about a meta refresh in your page?  See: http://academyoftumblr.tumblr.com/post/5700731004/redirect-to-a-new-url